# How to manage OS updates in an AWS autoscaling environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, autoscaling

I am looking to implement Autoscaling for my website using 'AWS Autoscaling Target Groups and Load Balancer'.

As the first step, I have created an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) based on the current EC2 instance, and I am using it as a scale base.

My question is when the Autoscaling kicks in and duplicate the Instances, it seems that it uses the AMI created and I wonder how can we manage the OS updates like Security updates to the Kernel e.g. yum updates, apt-get updates etc.

In this type of Scenario what the most simplest way to manage the OS updates in an Autoscaling environment?

Comment: One option: see [Patch an AMI and update an Auto Scaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-walk-patch-windows-ami-autoscaling.html).

Comment: Does your Auto Scaling group often launch new instances and terminate old instances (eg add/remove each day)? If so, there's no need to update existing instances since they are short-lived. You could just include update commands on first launch.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It does add/remove everyday, however i have core VM that is outside of the autoscaling group which doesn't get destroy at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Launch Template, you can specify an **User Data** script in the **Advanced Details** section. This script will run when the new EC2 instance is starting up.

This script can contain OS updates and other environment setup. You can read further about User Data scripts in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).